# Putting text on an image in Actionscript 3

Tags: image, actionscript-3, text

I may be missing something obvious.  I have large background images.  I want to put some text on top of them.  Currently the background image hides the text, I want the text on top of the background image.

I did some searches, and find plenty of information about including small images in text.  That's not what I want to do.  There is no relation between the image and the text.  addChildAt() does not help.  The background image has addChild before the text has addChild.

This is generally easy to do in other languages, which leads me to think I'm missing something.  What is it?

Added in response to question: The background image and text are coming from different objects, which is why addChildAt does not work.

Comment: Post some code. If you're adding(addChild) the text after the image it should work unless you're messing with child order in the parent.

Comment: The code is complex.  The background image and text are coming from different objects, which is why addChildAt does not work.

Comment: You've probably made it more complex than it has to be. Post the relevant parts of the code please.

Comment: The text can be added as a sibling of the Bitmap instance you're using to display the background and can be set to a display list index higher than the background

Comment: Yes, it's probably the complexity of the code that is causing the problem. It's not worth posting the code here- since I know that text can overlay graphics I'll figure it out.  Thanks.